# Overload () operator in Python

Tags: python, operator-overloading

I am trying to learn currying in Python for my class and I have to overload the () operator for it. However, I do not understand how can I can go about overloading the () operator. Can you explain the logic behind overloading the parentheses? Should I overload first ( and then ) or can I do any of these? Also, is there special name for parentheses operator?

Comment: [Emulating callable objects](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-callable-objects)

Answer (score 75, accepted):

You can make an object callable by implementing the `__call__` method:

```
class FunctionLike(object):
    def __call__(self, a):
        print("I got called with {!r}!".format(a))

fn = FunctionLike()
fn(10)

# --> I got called with 10!
```

Comment: Can I make basic operations with that callable object, such as addition?

Comment: You can provide almost all the language operations: http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-names

Comment: Is `()` a call operator that essentially calls the object in question with a certain argument (or absence thereof)?