# Implicitly call method when instance name is called

Tags: python

In an instance, is there a way I can call a method implicitly when I am calling just the instance name?

So for example if I have this

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, html):
       self.html = html
    def _render_html_(self):
       # omitted
       pass

>>> some_fancy_html = """(omitted)"""
>>> mc = MyClass(some_fancy_html)

## So instead of
>>> mc._render_html_()

## I would like to call
>>> mc
### to implicitly call the method _render_html()
```

Is that possible?

---

## Background

In the Panda's source code I can see this in a docstring:

```
    Notes
    -----
    Most styling will be done by passing style functions into
    ``Styler.apply`` or ``Styler.applymap``. Style functions should
    return values with strings containing CSS ``'attr: value'`` that will
    be applied to the indicated cells.

    If using in the Jupyter notebook, Styler has defined a ``_repr_html_``
    to automatically render itself. Otherwise call Styler.render to get
    the generated HTML.
```

In the second paragraph it says:

`` Styler has defined a `_repr_html_` to automatically render itself ``

Source: 
[Github: Pandas](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/1263e1a9cac179f453aa6223f00cbaa3e158a878/pandas/io/formats/style.py#L93)

Comment: In __init__ you can make it call __render_html(self)?

Comment: `mc()` will execute constructor of class.

Comment: No it won't, the constructor will be called when you do `mc = MyClass(...`. See my answer below for what happens when you call `mc()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can do that. I'd rather overload the parentheses operator, just like [it's explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15719243/276451).

```
>>> class MyClass:
...     def __init__(self, html):
...             self.html = html
...     def __call__(self):
...             print(self.html)
... 
>>> mc = MyClass("Hello, world")
>>> mc
<__main__.MyClass instance at 0x7f3a27a29bd8>
>>> mc()
Hello, world
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `_render_html`, call it `__call__`. This will be called by `mc()`. The step further than this - dropping the brackets in the calling code - is not possible, but you can come close if you make `_render_html` a property like so:

```
class MyClass:
    @property
     def html(self):
         pass
```

Then you can do `mc.html`, without the brackets, to call that function.

Comment: I like your second solution a lot. But the original question was about omitting any attributes / method calls. Hence I accepted Jose's solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to assign this function to some variable:

```
mc = MyClass._render_html_(MyClass(some_fancy_html))
```

Then you when you call mc it will call class method.
Of course, you can always pass already existing class object as a self:

```
some_fancy_html = """(omitted)"""
mc = MyClass(some_fancy_html)
method = MyClass._render_html_(mc)
```

Then typing `method` will execute same what would do: `mc._render_html_()`

Comment: This is a good approach in general but its important to mention that it doesnt necessarily match what OP wants. Particularly if `mc` tracks any state that the method depends on, calling that method once and holding on to the return value won't reflect any changes to that state.

Comment: Thank you for mentioning this! It is actually hard to match what OP wants since `_render_html_` function is empty. Anyway, I am glad you mentioned this.